# Type Mismatch Error InStr with two string variables

Tags: vba

I am trying to to check if a current value in a string already exists in a given string. I am using two variables for the parent string(existing string in a cell, active cell) and the search string . If the current string exactly exists in the parent string then a message box pops asking if the user wants to paste the same content .

I get a type mismatch error at the first IF condition . Can you please help me understand what the issue is ?

```
If (InStr(ActiveCell.Value, NRemark, vbBinaryCompare)) = 0 Then
Exit Sub
Else
Lresponse = MsgBox("You have already synced the same content . Would you like to  continue ?", vbYesNo)
    If Lresponse = vbYes Then
    GoTo V1 ' goes to the loop to append NRemark to the parent string
    Else
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at arguments in InStr:

> Function InStr([Start], [String1], [String2], [Compare As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare])

The first argument is [Start], which in your case should probably be a constant of 1 value.

> If (InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, NRemark, vbBinaryCompare)) = 0 Then ...

This should work, at least temporarily, until you encounter empty cells, cells with errors, etc., in which case it will break again.

Also, I can't tell what type your NRemark variable is. It has to be a string, so if it's a cell, you should put NRemark.Value instead.

Comment: NRemark is string contents in a cell .  Do I have to still put NRemark.value ?

Answer (score 4):

Way late on the answer here, but ran into this same problem today - because the ActiveCell.Value is a Variant (Type Undetermined), the system sees that as you trying to use the optional [start] variable, so the type mismatch actually occurs because it thinks your compare variable should be a string.

I was using cel.FormulaR1C1 to try to manipulate a variable and that is also a Variant type, so it caused this same problem.